# Apache rewrite URL but don't rewrite certain folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I am using Apache to rewrite my URLs into clean URLs.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
```

Currently this rewrites directories too, which is what I want, since I want everything run through my router/index.php file.

What I would like to do however, is have one folder that I can access directly.  This is for lib files such as .js and .css files.  I know how to do this with an Alias, but I can't use that in a .htaccess file, which I need to use.

How can I not rewrite a specific folder, eg. called "lib"?

**EDIT:**

I did find the following example of how to fake an Alias in .htaccess, but I can't get it working:

```
RewriteRule /old-folder /new-folder [PT]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/?lib/.+$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
```